# Play Store SearchBar variable width

Tags: html, css, google-play, width

If you go to Google Play Store Website,you will notice that the width of the SearchBar at the top changes if you change the window width.

Can someone please give me an example on how I can achieve such variable width behaviour using just HTML and CSS?

CSS

```
        body {
        margin:0;
        min-width:960px;
    }
    #upperbar {
        background-color:#F1F1F1;
        white-space:nowrap;
        height:60px;
        width:100%;
    }
    #logobardiv {
        margin:10px 20px 10px 30px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    #logo {
        height:39px;
        width:183px;
    }
    #searchbardiv {
        font-size:0;
        display:inline-block;
        height:100%;
        padding-left:10px;
        vertical-align:middle;
        white-space:nowrap;
        min-width:200px;
    }
    #searchbar {
        height:28px;
        /*max-width:589px;*/
        max-width:100%;
        width:589px;
        min-width:545px;
        font-size:16px;
        border:1px solid #A8A8A8;
        border-right:none;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    #searchbar:hover {
        border:1px solid black;
        border-right:none;
    }
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color:#A9A9A9;
        padding:0 0 0 7px;
    }
    #searchbutton {
        vertical-align:middle;
        background:#4584F0;
        height:28px;
        width:60px;
        display:inline-block;
        border:1px solid transparent;
        border-top-right-radius:2px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:2px;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        outline:none;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
    #searchbuttonimg {
        vertical-align:middle;
        background:url(images/search.png) no-repeat center;
        display:inline-block;
        height:100%;
        width:26px;
    }
    #signindiv {
        display:inline-block;
        height:100%;
        white-space:nowrap;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    #appsimg {
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="upperbar">
        <div id="logobardiv">
            <img id="logo" src="https://www.gstatic.com/android/market_images/web/play_logo_x2.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="searchbardiv">
            <input id="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
            <button id="searchbutton">  <span id="searchbuttonimg"></span>

            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="signindiv">
            <img id="appsimg" src="images/apps.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L9825j6o/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `display:flex` to achieve the variable length of the elements.

Refer the below link for a good explanation

[FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

simple way is you need to set a 3 different width max-width, min-widtht and actual width

like

```
input{
max-width:100%; 
min-width:300px;
width:800px;
}
```

Comment: in the play store site,the input is changing width,but i can't get it to do with the above code

Comment: let's check https://jsfiddle.net/Muthukumaru/Lyz5chs3/1/ hear its responsible only window-size<600px and window-size>300px. we can change these sizes. in play store as well this happening its not responsible in all window sizes they sets the limit.